# Lua Pattern Matching

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have a file that I get from pulling out values from a Microsoft Lync conversation that has RTF formatting tags.  An example file would be like:

> {\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 >Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}}
>   {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
>   {*\generator Riched20 15.0.4420}{*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 
>   \pard\cf1\embo\f0\fs20 Craig...\embo0  \embo please\embo0  \embo close\embo0  \embo >out\embo0  \embo of\embo0  \embo your\embo0  \embo old\embo0  \embo client\embo0  \embo >and\embo0  \embo re-open\embo0\f1\par
>   {*\lyncflags rtf=1}}

Using Lua scripting I'm trying to remove the RTF tags and just pull out the text of the conversation.  So the result of my function should be:

> Craig... please close out of your old client and re-open

I've tried using a string.gsub with a regex to match the patterns and replace them with a blank space to only leave the text but it's not working.  Here is the code that I have so far for the string.gsub:

```
result = string.gsub(s, "\{\*?\\[^{}]+}|[{}]|\\\n?[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?[ ]?", " ")
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Additional:

> > user1@capital.com @ 2013-01-18 17:48:03Z       (TO: user2@capital.com)

{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{*\generator Riched20 15.0.4420}{*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\cf1\embo\f0\fs20 works\embo0  \embo for\embo0  \embo me..\embo0  \embo how\embo0  \embo about\embo0  \embo embedding\embo0  \embo pictures?\embo0\f1\par
{*\lyncflags rtf=1}}

> > user1@capital.com @ 2013-01-18 17:48:57Z       (TO: user2@capital.com)

{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{*\generator Riched20 15.0.4420}{*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\cf1\embo\f0\fs20 I\embo0  \embo see\embo0  \embo it\embo0\f1\par
{*\lyncflags rtf=1}}

> > user1@capital.com @ 2013-01-18 17:49:27Z       (TO: user2@capital.com)

{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{*\generator Riched20 15.0.4420}{*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\cf1\embo\f0\fs20 let's\embo0  \embo try\embo0  \embo a\embo0  \embo meeting.\embo0\f1\par
{*\lyncflags rtf=1}}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What output does the regex you've given result in?

Comment: If in the end you are still not satisfied with the pattern matching solution you might want to check you the [lpeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html) library

Answer (score 2):

Lua patterns don't have `or` operators (`|`) or optional groupings (`(?:...)?`). Something like this may work:

```
s:match("{(.+)}"):gsub("%b{}", ""):gsub("\\%w+", "")
```

will return:

```
"    Craig...  please  close  >out  of  your  old  client  >and  re-open "
```

First `gsub` removes all pairs of `{}` along with their content, the second `gsub` removes all rtf tags (although there seem to be some that allow spaces in them, so you may need to tweak the pattern).

Comment: That's close, but in some instances I get:  Attempt to index a nil value as my error

Comment: Additional info added to problem statement above.  Where the email addresses are indented there are two greater than characters in my formatting.

Comment: I'm confused: I don't get any failures and don't see email addresses. All I get are these three messages: `"    works  for  me..  how  about  embedding  pictures? "`, `"    I  see  it "`, and `"    let's  try  a  meeting. "`.

Comment: You can remove "greater than" signs and collapse whitespaces with something like this `:gsub("%s+>?", " ")`.

Comment: What if I have a string get passed that doesn't contain any RTF formatting?  Will the s:match still work or do I need to put something in before that to check for the formatting?

Comment: You can either check for that or do something like this: `(s:match("{(.+)}") or ''):gsub("%b{}", ""):gsub("\\%w+", "")`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
local s = '{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 >Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;} {*\generator Riched20 15.0.4420}{*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\cf1\embo\f0\fs20 Craig...\embo0 \embo please\embo0 \embo close\embo0 \embo >out\embo0 \embo of\embo0 \embo your\embo0 \embo old\embo0 \embo client\embo0 \embo >and\embo0 \embo re-open\embo0\f1\par {*\lyncflags rtf=1}}\n'
    ..'{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;} {*\generator Riched20 15.0.4420}{*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\cf1\embo\f0\fs20 works\embo0 \embo for\embo0 \embo me..\embo0 \embo how\embo0 \embo about\embo0 \embo embedding\embo0 \embo pictures?\embo0\f1\par {*\lyncflags rtf=1}}\n'
    ..'{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;} {*\generator Riched20 15.0.4420}{*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\cf1\embo\f0\fs20 I\embo0 \embo see\embo0 \embo it\embo0\f1\par {*\lyncflags rtf=1}}\n'
    ..'{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;} {*\generator Riched20 15.0.4420}{*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\cf1\embo\f0\fs20 let\'s\embo0 \embo try\embo0 \embo a\embo0 \embo meeting.\embo0\f1\par {*\lyncflags rtf=1}}\n'
local text = string.gsub(s, '{(.-)}[}]?', ''):gsub('embo',''):gsub('0',''):gsub('iewkind4uc1 pardcf1',''):gsub('1par',''):gsub('s2',''):gsub('>','')
print(text)
```

> output
>
> `Craig...  please  close  out  of  your  old  client  and  re-open
>
>       works  for  me..  how  about  embedding  pictures?
>
>       I  see  it
>
>       let's  try  a  meeting.`